# Reading the XML file having special character in the Tag using vb script

Tags: vbscript

I am writing vbscript to read some data from xml file. My xml file has a special character in its tag name like "q12:Policy" becouse of this my script is not able to read the tag. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15396987/603855 for sample code to deal with namespaces.

Comment: I am unable to read teh nodes from xml file, I checked by putting echos, its not even reading single node. How to share my script here?