# How to modify the content of an XML node using python?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I have a simple problem that, i want to update/modify the content of an xml node using python. I am using python 3.6 version.

I want to write a python script that, will modify the status node content to "On" and directoryName node to "Users/

```
 <main>
        <status>off</status>

        <directoryName>nothing</directoryName>

 </main>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a simple XML file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605680/creating-a-simple-xml-file-using-python)

Comment: Not a duplicate but similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/8236107/1513933

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and Replace Values in XML using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523886/find-and-replace-values-in-xml-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I forgot to write at the end

```
 xmlHandler = "System_Settings/System_controller.xml"

    xmlDom=ElementTree.parse(xmlHandler)

    xmlDom.find("status").text = "on"
    print(xmlDom.find("status").text)

    xmlDom.write(xmlHandler)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to install an additional package, take a look at [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). It makes parsing html and xml quite simple.

```py
import bs4
xml = """
<main>
    <status>off</status>
    <directoryName>nothing</directoryName>
</main>"""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(xml, "xml")
soup.status.string="on"
print(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [lxml](https://lxml.de/) library (which is also used by BeautifulSoup):

```py
from lxml import etree

node = etree.XML("""
<main>
    <status>off</status>
    <directoryName>nothing</directoryName>
</main>""")
status = "On"

status_node = node.xpath("/main/status")[0]
status_node.text = status
```

Then with `print(etree.tounicode(node))`, you get:

```xml
<main>
    <status>On</status>
    <directoryName>nothing</directoryName>
</main>
```